# OpenMP with clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, openmp

I was trying an openmp code with clang compiler as specified in

http://clang-omp.github.io/

I downloaded the code via git and did `make` and `make install`. It successfully installed the clang compiler with openmp support. But when I try to compile a sample code (specified in the above link), I get the following error :

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liomp5

I did not specify path to include and lib as mentioned in the site, but I intend to specify them while compiling on command line with *-L* and *-I* options.

$`clang -I/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include -fopenmp test.c -o test`

However, I could not find path for *iomp5* lib and hence I got the above error. Can someone please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe you should first follow the usage steps provided on the site and see if it works. Furthermore, the library path **is** provided there: `/install/prefix/lib:<OpenMP library path>`.

Comment: @SebastianDressler I had difficulty in locating path of OpenMP library. Can you tell me how to find path of OpenMP libraray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to build openmp library libiomp5. You can take the latest source code here
http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/openmp/trunk/